# how can I store the results of a loop into a variable? in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, store

a truly beginners question, I am applying a loop on a list with the following line of code:

```
for(i in 1:length(zz)){ if (length(zz[[i]])>2) {print(zz[[i]])}}
```

and I am obtaining what I want, as I visualize it in the console. However I can't find the way to store this into a variable, so I can make use of it later on.

can you please help me with this?

thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you just filter your list as follows:

```
out <- zz[sapply(zz, length) > 2]
```

where `sapply(zz, length)` gives you the length of your list items.

Comment: definitely have a look at `?lapply` when you're thinking of a trivial task within a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
out <- vector("numeric", length(zz)) #type depends on what zz is

for(i in 1:length(zz))
    if(length(zz[[i]] > 2)
        out[i] = zz[[i]]
```

As the others note, the convention in R is to do this with a member of the `apply` family.